# Configurar textbot para imprimir en vb.net

Tags: vb.net

una consulta para vb.net. Como puedo hacer para que un textbot al momento de que se llene, este me mande a imprimir sin necesidad de presionar el boton

Answer (score 0):

- Logre hacerlo de la siguiente manera

If Len(Me.Textbox1.Text) = 13 Then

```
        Me.Btnimprimir.Focus()
    End If
```

el numero 13 indica la cantidad de caracteres que se le permite tener al textbox, es modificable